# Finding only unique value in each column in a d

Tags: r

I have the below data frame df1. (Edited to have different numbers of repeated value in the data frame.)

```
> dput(df1)
structure(list(...1 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), x = c(5, 10, 
20, 20, 25), y = c(2, 6, 6, 6, 10), z = c(6, 2, 1, 8, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

  >df1
            x     y     z 
  a         5     2     6
  b        10     6     2
  c        20     6     1
  d        20     6     8
  e        25    10     1
```

I would like to get a df2 which only has the unique values from each column 'x','y' and 'z'.
I tried:

```
df2<-apply(df1,2, unique)
df2 <- do.call(cbind, df2)
df2 <- as.data.frame(df2)
```

Desired output:

```
      >df2
        x     y     z 
        5     2     6
       10     6     2
       20     10    1
       25           8
```

Comment: As mentioned in the comments, what to do when each column has a different number of unique values? Please, provide an example and state what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tibbles can't have rownames so it creates a new column with it in your data. You can delete the first column and then use `unique` on all columns.

```
library(dplyr)
df1$...1 <- NULL
df1 %>% summarise(across(.fns = unique))

#     x     y     z
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     5     2     6
#2    10     6     2
#3    20     8     1
#4    25    10     8
```

Or in base R :

```
df2 <- data.frame(sapply(df1, unique))
```

---

For unequal unique values in the column you could use :

```
tmp <- lapply(df1, unique)
data.frame(sapply(tmp, `[`, 1:max(lengths(tmp))))

#   x  y z
#1  5  2 6
#2 10  6 2
#3 20 10 1
#4 25 NA 8
```

Comment: Possibly worth mentioning that, while this works for the given sample data, it relies on there being an equal number of duplicates in every column. Otherwise it will try (and fail) to create a df with differing column lengths and you'll need to use a different data structure.

Comment: When I have different number of repeated values in a column, the value seem to repeat itself again. Is there a way to overcome it?

Comment: @kaix See updated answer to make this work for unequal number of unique values.